# Strict Folder and File Permissions for WordPress Themes Folder

Tags: theme-development, security

My client is working with a third party security team that insists on having WordPress theme folder I created set to 644 for folders and 444 on files. Is this even possible with WordPress?

Comment: Did you read the docs about it? There are these two topics about the file permissions https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions/ and https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the recommended permissions are 755 for folders and 644 for files. However I was able to test files with 444 permissions successfully.